# logloss equivalent for poisson regression

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, accuracy, calibration, log-loss

I have a Poisson regression model, and I would like to measure the discrepancy between actual counts and predicted counts. For binary classification model, the log-loss metrics fits for this purpose. Is there any metrics alike for Poisson models? Similarly, is there any package or is possible to code a function in R for it? Thanks in advance

Comment: The log-loss is the log-likelihood of the bernoulli distribution.  You want the log-likelihood of the poisson distribution.

Comment: It really depends on what aspects of the original you want equivalence of. The present answer offers a very sensible choice, but it really depends on what you mean by "equivalent"

Answer (score 3):

When fitting a GLM, the deviance is something you'd like to see as low as possible.  I believe for a binomial GLM, the binomial deviance is already the log loss.  If you run a Poisson GLM, the Poisson deviance should be the number you're looking for.  It's spit out by default in `glm()` in R.

Check it out what it actually is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_(statistics)).

A bonus benefit to using deviance, is that you can use it to compare models via a $\chi^2$ test.